# What is ArcCatalog?

Tags: spatial-database, esri-geodatabase, arccatalog

What is it, what does it do, and how is it related to geodatabases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the ESRI site and it will explain it to you in detail.

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?id=3026&pid=3025&topicname=An_overview_of_ArcCatalog

Comment: More appropriate would have been http://lmgtfy.com/?q=ArcCatalog

Answer (score 0):

Even Google Defines it:

http://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=define%3AArcCatalog&btnG=Search&aq=&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1